# Why IMG tag of HTML renders null on Firefox?

Tags: html, tags

```
<html>
<body>

    <img id="j_id58" width="800" border="0" height="400" src="c:/test/tmp/imageEE3A7BA3F55BC67061FD778F1B0136D6.png"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Why does this not render any image when I open it on firefox but does it on IE 6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet this will work if you use a `file://` URL instead of a filename.

```
<html>
<body>
<img id="j_id58" width="800" border="0" height="400"
     src="file:///c/test/tmp/imageEE3A7BA3F55BC67061FD778F1B0136D6.png"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Try that.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox doesn't support using the `"C:/"`-style path.

Instead use a relative URL or a real URL to that file hosted by a web server.

IE6 does support this.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox requires the "file:///"-prefix when referencing local files.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers above, this is likely to fail if you load your HTML from an HTTP server.

Comment: A true classic... "But I see the images when I try it from my computer"... :)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you need a *src* attribute with a file:\\ scheme.

Try file:///C://test/tmp/imageEE3A7BA3F55BC67061FD778F1B0136D6.png in the *src* and see if it works.